# Possible to have nested triggers?

Tags: jquery, triggers

I have this code snippet that works sometimes, but sometimes it just stops after the first trigger. This could be due to the slowness of my computer sometimes. But ideally I want the second trigger to fire only as a result of the first one completing. It would be nice if it was possible to have a callback function on the trigger event..

```
$('#div1').fadeIn(1000, function(){
    $('#first').trigger('click');
    $('#footer').fadeIn(2000, function(){ 
         $('#second').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Any suggestions for how to get it working better?
If possible I would also like to have a third trigger...

Comment: You could possibly attach the footer.fadeIn function to the first trigger.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the code.  It will run those four events in sequence, each time waiting for the animation to finish before proceeding.  What happens in the two click() functions?  What appears to be the problem?  If there are animations in the tigger('click') functions, it won't wait for those to complete.

Comment: The second click event is dependent on the first, so if the first one is slightly delayed then the code breaks. Sometimes it does work, but other times, depending on speed I think, it's like the second one probably tries to happen before the first has completed, but it can't if the div - loaded by $(#first).click - hasn't fully loaded in time.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do something like:

```
$('#div1').fadeIn(1000, function(){
    $('#first').trigger('click');
});

$('#first').click(function() {
    $('#footer').fadeIn(2000, function(){ 
         $('#second').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Comment: Wasn't what I had in mind, it would mean having to use global variables and stuff and would get very messy later. But I'll try out something like this tomorrow, modifying the #first event function somehow... Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I was a bit unclear in that comment, sorry. I was just thinking ahead about how a solution like this would mean I'd have to modify already-written functions etc. Whereas I was hoping I could just nicely nest each trigger within the same block of code.

Comment: @grainne: You could wrap it all in an anonymous function to prevent globals. But perhaps there is a better way. We need to see what you exactly have/want in order to make a good decision.